# Сортировка слиянием из сортировки простыми вставками

Tags: сортировка, c++

Уважаемые программисты, мне срочно нужно переделать мою сортировку(простыми вставками) на сортировку слиянием. Вставками не принимают : (. Помогите пожалуйста. Сдать утром надо, башка уже не варит. Вот кусок кода с сортировкой, все необходимые еще участки кода прикреплю, если нужно будет. Спасибо

```
void tlist::sort()
{
    node *prt=first;
    Train *tem;// это мой абстрактный класс поезд, в который входят грузовой и пассажирский поезда
    // для элементов двусвязного списка с первого до последнего
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        // для элементов двусвязного списка с первого до предпоследнего
        for (int l=0; l<(count-1); l++)
        {
            //если курс поточного элемента больше чем у следующего
            if (prt->data->getnumb()>prt->next->data->getnumb())//getnumb это метод получения номера поезда
            {
                tem = prt->next->data;
                prt->next->data = prt->data;
                prt->data = tem;
            }
            prt=prt->next; //переход к следующему элементу
        } // end of "for (int l=0; l<(count-1); l++)"
        prt = first; //переходим снова на первый
    }// end of "for (int i=0; i<count;i++)"
}
```

Comment: @BigBobo, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Я сделал работу. В которой описал абстрактный класс поезд, в который входят пассажирский и грузовой поезда. Одним из заданий была сортировка. Чтобы из меню(оно у меня есть отдельно) можно было просматривать от последнего поезда к первому и от первого к последнему. Я это сделал методом простых вставок, но мне сказали до завтра переделать сортировку и сделать ее методом слияния. Я не понял как это сделать, время поджимает, вот я и написал сюда.

Comment: @BigBobo, если я правильно понял Вы просто двигаете указатели на данные по элементам списка. Логично.

--

IMHO mergesort так просто не сделать. И программа из 20 строк не получится. Обычно mergesort применяют к массиву, высчитывая индексы сливаемых вместе кусочков. Со списками такая схема не пройдет.

Думаю (возможно ошибаюсь и в инете есть что-то получше) надо сделать список списков по 2 элемента. Которые потом сливаются в два раза более длинные упорядоченные. Всего log N проходов. На последнем получится 1 список - результат.

--

В принципе довольно интересно, жаль что я сейчас занят.

Comment: Если у вас вдруг появится время, помогите пожалуйста. Я такое не сделаю пока что сам. Слишком ограниченные познания. Я до среды могу это не сдавать. Если вдруг вы освободитесь,буду очень рад вашей подмоге. Спасибо.

Comment: А Вы в google не пробовали искать?

Я быстренько глянул:

    сортировка списков слиянием

и вот это http://www.williamspublishing.com/PDF/978-5-8459-1650-1/part.pdf кажется подойдет. 

Внимательно не смотрел, а Вам советую разобрать прог. 5.7 на стр. 329. Оказалась совсем коротенькая (и метод другой, нежели мне в голову пришел, тут IMHO покрасивей будет).

Если подойдет -- отпишите сюда.

Comment: Да. Это должно подойти. Если верить тому, что написано. Для связных списков как раз.

Comment: Вы могли бы пожалуйста помочь сделать по методу, как в том пдф файле. А то я что-то вообще не понимаю как из моего метода нужный сделать. У них там вроде рекурсивный метод коротенький, но рекурсия для меня проблема.

Comment: @BigBobo, ну, Вашу программу я делать не буду, а какой-нибудь обобщенный вариант на Си для своих списков ближе к ночи попробую выложить (наверное на pastebin, если он еще работает).

--

А с рекурсией советую разобраться. В принципе там просто. 

"Хитроватым" способом (один указатель идет на след., а другой прыгает через один элемент) находим середину списка и "терминируем" первую часть.

Потом сливаем, рекурсивно вызывая себя для каждого из списков и возвращаем список, полученный в результате слияния. 

Обратите внимение, что все функции возвращают указатель на первый элемент списка.

Comment: @BigBobo, я положил файл (list2.h) в http://pastebin.com/EVwuTAiF

Сортировка в конце, функция называется list2_sort().

Пока посмотрите, а я в ответе напишу поподробнее с примером вызова.

Answer (score 1):

[@BigBobo](/users/15759/bigbobo), вот обещанный ответ.

Программка, которая делает двусвязный список и сортирует его,
вызывая функцию сортировки слиянием из list2.h (см. http://pastebin.com/EVwuTAiF)

Сортировка устойчивая, сложность O(N log N).

Особенностью этих списков является передача в функции манипулирования данными
не адреса пользовательской структуры а адреса ссылок на следующий/предыдущий
элементы списка, которые находятся внутри такой структуры.

Для доступа к данным по возвращаемому функциями из list2.h указателю используется макрос list_entry().

Такой подход позволяет обрабатывать заранее не известные в функциях работы
со списком структуры пользователя, а также размещать одну и ту же структуру
в разных списках (естественно, для каждого списка свои переменные связи).

```
// lisort.c test "list2.h" sorting functions
// gcc -std=gnu99 -I../include ...
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/time.h>

long long
mtime()
{
  struct timeval t;

  gettimeofday(&t, NULL);
  long long mt = (long long)t.tv_sec * 1000 + t.tv_usec / 1000;
  return mt;
}

#include "list2.h"

struct data1 {
  int no;
  char *val;
  List2 list;
};

int cmp1 (List2 *p1, List2 *p2)
{
  struct data1 *d1 = list_entry(p1, struct data1, list),
    *d2 = list_entry(p2, struct data1, list);

  return strcmp(d1->val, d2->val);
}

int cmp2 (const void *v1, const void *v2)
{
  struct data1 *d1 = (typeof(d1))v1, *d2 = (typeof(d2))v2;

  return strcmp(d1->val, d2->val);
}

void
print_data1_list (const char *msg, List2head *t)
{
  puts(msg);
  List2 *listitem;
  struct data1 *p;

  list2_for_each (listitem, t) {
    p = list_entry(listitem, struct data1, list);
    printf ("%d [%s]\n", p->no, p->val);
  }
}

void
get_data1_list (const char *msg, List2head *t)
{
  puts(msg);
  char str[1000];
  int  i = 0;
  struct data1 *p;

  while (fgets(str, 1000, stdin)) {
    str[strlen(str) - 1] = 0;
    p = (typeof(p))malloc(sizeof(*p));
    p->no = ++i;
    p->val = strdup(str);
    list2_add_tail(&p->list, t);
  }

}

void
genlist (List2head *t, int n)
{
  char str[100];

  srand(0);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    sprintf(str, "%d", rand());
    struct data1 *p = (typeof(p))malloc(sizeof(*p));
    p->no = i + 1;
    p->val = strdup(str);
    list2_add_tail(&p->list, t);
  }
}

void
fill_a (struct data1 a[], int n)
{
  char str[100];

  srand(0);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    sprintf(str, "%d", rand());
    a[i].no = i + 1;
    a[i].val = strdup(str);
  }
}

#define N 1000000

int
main ()
{
  LIST2_HEAD(t1);
  get_data1_list("enter test1 strings (end ^D)", &t1);
  print_data1_list("test1 source data", &t1);
  list2_sort(&t1, cmp1);
  print_data1_list("test1 sort (l_mergesort()) data", &t1);

  INIT_LIST2_HEAD(&t1);
  genlist(&t1, N);
  long long mtime(), start = mtime();
  list2_sort(&t1, cmp1);
  printf ("list2_sort: %d %lld msec\n", 
          (int)list2_power(&t1), mtime() - start);

  struct data1 *a = (typeof(a))malloc(sizeof(*a) * N);
  fill_a(a, N);
  start = mtime();  
  qsort (a, N, sizeof(*a), cmp2);
  printf ("system qsort: %d %lld msec\n", 
          N, mtime() - start);

}
```

Пример использования

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~/src/dispro/BM/tst$ g++ -O2  -I ../include/ lisort.c 
avp@avp-ubu1:~/src/dispro/BM/tst$ ./a.out 
enter test1 strings (end ^D)
1
qq
a
qq
qq
test1 source data
1 [1]
2 [qq]
3 [a]
4 [qq]
5 [qq]
test1 sort (l_mergesort()) data
1 [1]
3 [a]
2 [qq]
4 [qq]
5 [qq]
list2_sort: 1000000 663 msec
system qsort: 1000000 602 msec
avp@avp-ubu1:~/src/dispro/BM/tst$
```

На всякий случай повторю тут функцию сортировки из list2.h

```
/*
 * Слияние списков, завершающихся next == 0,
 * в соответствии с fcmp(elem1, elem2) (returns N < 0, 0 for EQUAL or N > 0)
 * l1, l2 указатели на первые элементы списков
 * указатели prev становятся неактуальными
 */
static List2 *
merge2lists (List2 *l1, List2 *l2, int (*fcmp)(List2 *e1, List2 *e2))
{
  List2 result = {0, 0}, *cur = &result;

  while (l1 && l2) 
    if (fcmp(l1, l2) <= 0) {
      cur->next = l1; cur = l1; l1 = l1->next;
    } else {
      cur->next = l2; cur = l2; l2 = l2->next;
    }
  cur->next = (l1 ? l1 : l2); // оставшиеся элементы запишем в хвост result
  return result.next;
}

/*
 * Сортировка списка по указателю на его первый элемент
 * в соответствии с fcmp(elem1, elem2) (returns N < 0, 0 for EQUAL or N > 0)
 * указатели prev становятся неактуальными
 */
static List2 *
l_mergesort (List2 *list, int (*fcmp)(List2 *e1, List2 *e2))
{
  if (list == 0 || list->next == 0) return list;
  List2 *a = list, *b = list->next;
  // хитро делим список пополам. b бежит через элемент
  while (b && b->next) {
    list = list->next; b = b->next->next;
  }
  b = list->next; 
  list->next = 0; // разделим, terminate первую половину

  return merge2lists(l_mergesort(a, fcmp), l_mergesort(b, fcmp), fcmp);
}

/*
 * mergesort двусвязного списка 
 * в соответствии с fcmp(elem1, elem2) (returns N < 0, 0 for EQUAL or N > 0)
 */
static void
list2_sort (List2head *list, int (*fcmp)(List2 *e1, List2 *e2))
{
  if (list->size < 2)
    return;
  List2 *slist = l_mergesort(list->head, fcmp), *p = 0;

  list->head = slist;
  // восстановим указатели prev
  while (slist) {
    slist->prev = p;
    p = slist;
    slist = slist->next;
  }
  list->tail = p;
}
```

Динамически выделяемую память я здесь просто не освобождаю. Вообще-то это надо делать.

Что непонятно, спрашивайте. Постараюсь объяснить.

Comment: Спасибо большое за такую огромную работу. Я постараюсь все разобрать..Если уж совсем не пойму, то спрошу. Спасибо огромное.

Comment: С pastebin-а все нормально взяли? А то у меня иногда с ним какие-то "глюки" бывают.

Comment: Нормально все взялось